# Prove that a subspace of a subspace is a subspace of the entire topological space.

Tags: general-topology

This question does not seem as tricky as it sounds, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be really appreciated

My attempt: Let X be a topological space. If Y ⊂ X is a subspace of X. Then do I say Z ⊂ Y is a subspace of Y and prove that Z is a subspace of X?

I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction and would appreciate any hints or advice.

Thank you

Comment: You need to show that the induced topology of $Z$ as a subspace of $Y$ is the same as the induced topology of $Z$ as a subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 3):

The topology of $Z$ as a subspace of $Y$ is $\mathcal{T}_{Z,Y}=\{A\cap Z:A\subset Y$ is open$\}$, while the topology of $Z$ as a subspace of $X$ is $\mathcal{T}_{Z,X}=\{B\cap Z:B\subset X$ is open$\}$.

In order to prove that $\mathcal{T}_{Z,Y}=\mathcal{T}_{Z,X}$, notice that the topology of $Y$ as subspace of $X$ is $\mathcal{T}_{Y,X}=\{B\cap Y:B\subset X$ is open$\}$. Hence the equality follows from the fact that
$$B\cap Z=B\cap (Y\cap Z)=(B\cap Y)\cap Z,$$
because $Z\subset Y$.